# Coding error in my command box - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have got some code here, but I get the following error:

> Run-time error 1004
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

So hopefully someone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong. Still very new to all of this...

**What I want my userform to do**

I have a userform which is two pages, it uses multipage.

I want all my users to fill in details on the first page, called 'Main'. On this form is an option-button question: "Did the customer ask about a product today?".

If the answer to this question is 'no', the form should end after the command button is clicked, sending the relevant info to the worksheet.

If the answer to this question is 'yes', the form should automatically send the user to the 'Extra' page. The user completes this page, hits the command button on this second page, and the form will send the info from both pages into the same row of the worksheet.

**My Code**

***For the command button on the 'Main' page***

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

Dim closeForm As Boolean

'The form should close, unless ProductEnquiryYes is true
closeForm = True

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1


'Did customer ask about product?
If ProductEnquiryYes.Value = True Then
Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1
closeForm = False
Cells(emptyRow, 20).Value = 1
End If

If ProductEnquiryNo.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 21).Value = 1
End If

'Balance Enquiry
If BalanceEnquiry.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 23).Value = 1
End If

'Close Userform
If closeForm Then Unload Me

End Sub
```

***For the command button on the 'Extra' page***

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'If this checkbox is True, send value of 1 to the worksheet
If CAOpen.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 63).Value = 1
End If

Unload Me

End Sub
```

The command button works for the first page, and is returning the values correctly into the worksheet. However, the command button on the second page is not correct, and I do not know why. It's probably something obvious, so please forgive me.

When I hit debug, it is specifically this line that is highlighted in yellow:

```
Cells(emptyRow, 63).Value = 1
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think that the error is you use `emptyRow` in

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'If this checkbox is True, send value of 1 to the worksheet
If CAOpen.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 63).Value = 1
End If

Unload Me

End Sub
```

But it has not been initialized!
in `CommandButton1_Click` you have

```
Dim emptyRow As Long
```

so `emptyRow` is not global, but a local variable.

You have to recreate and recalculate `emptyRow` :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long
'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1


'If this checkbox is True, send value of 1 to the worksheet
If CAOpen.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 63).Value = 1
End If

Unload Me

End Sub
```

You can use the `Option Explicit` option to be more strict.

Comment: Hi smagnan -- excellent, thank you. This now makes the userform work. However, I want the values from the second command button to go into the *same* row. Now, the values go into the empty row below. Any ideas?

Comment: @AliLumsden didn't get well what you mean by "same row": If you mean the row above the empty row you can use the `Offset` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060%28v=office.15%29.aspx Like: `Cells(emptyRow, 63).Offset(-1,0).Value = 1` ... or I didn't get what you want

Comment: NOTE: If the above didn't answer your last comment, you can check the answer as accepted and ask a new question with more detail about this specific problem: It will help future users because it's not easy to explain a solution in the comments and because theese are two different questions.

Comment: Hi smagman, I accepted your answer and +vote. Thanks for the help.. still struggling with some errors, but for a different reason now ^.^